# inconsistent signal behavior? Only works for the first signal?

Tags: bash

Trying to have a script that is able to restart itself with `exec` (so it can pick up any "upgrade") given a specific signal (tried `SIGHUP` & `SIGUSR1`).

This seems to work the first time, but not the second, even tho the registration (`trap`) does recur in the `exec`ed instance (which is still the same PID).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x
readonly PROGNAME="${0}"

function run_prog()
{
  echo hi
  sleep 2
  echo ho
  sleep 1000 &
  wait $!
}


restart()
{
  sleep 5
  exec "${PROGNAME}"
}


trap restart  USR1
echo -e "TRAPS:"
trap
echo
run_prog
```

This is how I run it:

```
./tst.sh & TSTPID=$! # Starts ok, see both "hi" & "ho" messages
sleep 10
kill -USR1 ${TSTPID} # Restarts ok, see both "hi" & "ho" messages
sleep 10 
kill -USR1 ${TSTPID} # NOTHING HAPPENS
sleep 5
kill ${TSTPID}
```

Any idea why the second signal is ignored?  (some code, like de-registering the trap in the cleanup may just be paranoia)

Comment: Does the '-' in the trap declaration in cleanup() reset the signal to the default (not trapped)?  E.g. bash help trap.

Comment: It is, but I consider it paranoia.  The exec should actually reset trap (in C it does AFAIK)

Comment: and running `trap` with no params shows the current trap table.  When I run the above code it shows the same identical table for the first and the second execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you're execing from a signal handler, the signal code is continuing to run and continuing into oblivion, due to the exec, or preventing other cleanup code or daisy-chained handlers from executing.

Who knows what's going on in the blackbox of the OS signal handling code and bash's own layering over it that might be circumvented by exec. exec is a very draconian measure :-)

Also check out this [cool bash site](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php). I'm looking for the bash source code that handles signals. Just curious.

Your solution here is the right approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x
readonly PROGNAME="${0}"
DO_RESTART=

function run_prog()
{
  echo hi
  sleep 2
  echo ho
  sleep 1000 &
  SLEEPPID=$!
  #builtin
  wait ${SLEEPPID}
}

trap DO_RESTART=1 SIGUSR1
echo -e "TRAPS:"
trap -p
echo
run_prog
if [ -n "${DO_RESTART}" ]; then
  sleep 5
  kill ${SLEEPPID}
  exec "${PROGNAME}"
fi
```

Comment: now you are at a round 1024, goes well with your ID